# Как ускорить обработку изображения в Core Image?

Tags: ios, swift, opengles

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно обрабатывать изображения в Core Image. Чем больше разрешение изображения, тем дольше приходиться ждать его обработку. Также имеется UISlider, который меняет интенсивность фильтра, что приводит к вылету или зависанию приложения. Все хорошо работает только с маленькими изображениями, например 600x600.
Пример кода тестового класса GLKView:

```
import UIKit
import CoreImage
import GLKit

class CustomGLView: GLKView {
    //test filters 
    let clampFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIAffineClamp")!
    let blurFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")!
    let ciContext:CIContext

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        let glContext = EAGLContext(api: .openGLES2)
        ciContext = CIContext(
            eaglContext: glContext!,
            options: [
                kCIContextWorkingColorSpace: NSNull()
            ]
        )
        super.init(frame: frame, context: glContext!)
        enableSetNeedsDisplay = true
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        let glContext = EAGLContext(api: .openGLES2)
        ciContext = CIContext(
            eaglContext: glContext!,
            options: [
                kCIContextWorkingColorSpace: NSNull()
            ]
        )
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        context = glContext!
        enableSetNeedsDisplay = true
    }

      var inputImage: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            inputCIImage = inputImage.map { CIImage(image: $0)! }
        }
    }

     var blurRadius: Float = 0 {
        didSet {
            blurFilter.setValue(blurRadius, forKey: "inputRadius")
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    var inputCIImage: CIImage? {
        didSet { setNeedsDisplay() }
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        if let inputCIImage = inputCIImage {
            clampFilter.setValue(inputCIImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
            blurFilter.setValue(clampFilter.outputImage!, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
            let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: drawableWidth, height: drawableHeight)
            ciContext.draw(blurFilter.outputImage!, in: rect, from: inputCIImage.extent)
        }
    } 
}
```

Код ViewController'а:

```
import UIKit
import GLKit
import CoreImage

    class ViewController: UIViewController {
        //image
         let imageOriginal = UIImage(named: "pic_2")
         //my GLKView
        @IBOutlet weak var glView: CustomGLView!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
                //test image
                self.glView.inputImage = self.imageOriginal

            }

         //метод слайдера
        @IBAction func mySlider(_ sender: UISlider) {

                self.glView.blurRadius = sender.value
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

В контексте CI / CG мне в своем подобном приложении удалось оптимизировать реализацию так. С большими фото начинает подтормаживать, но не критично. 
Лучше тестировать на устройстве, симулятор тормозит. 
CIContext я инициализировал без OpenGL. 
Swift3:

```
@IBAction func sliderMoved(_ sender: UISlider) {


    let context = CIContext(options: nil)
    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls")

    let myQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive)

    myQueue.async {

        let ciImageLoaded = CIImage(cgImage: (self.imageLoaded?.cgImage)!)
        filter?.setValue(ciImageLoaded, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        filter?.setValue(NSNumber(value: sender.value as Float), forKey: kCIInputBrightnessKey)


    if let _output = filter?.outputImage, let _extent = filter?.outputImage?.extent {
        if let cgImage = context.createCGImage(_output, from: _extent) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.finalImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)

                self.imageView.image = self.finalImage
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Увы, но у меня тормозит((. Даже не знаю что за магия у Apple в родном приложении Фото творится.

Comment: @Metman там много хитростей, весь раздел об этом: (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_performance/ci_performance.html)

Comment: Прочитал документацию. Там есть несколько советов об улучшении производительности. Но почему-то не помогает. Я использую GLKView для рисования, немного быстрей, но все равно медленно.